# How to estimate a specific infinite matrix sum

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, numerical-linear-algebra, theta-functions

Let $M$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix with each diagonal element equal to $k$ and each non-diagonal element equal to $k-1$ where $n$ and $k$ are positive integers. Let $k < n$ and we can assume both $k$ and $n$ are large.

What is

$$S_{M,k} = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x^T M x}\;?$$

Is there some way to estimate this sum?

This was also posted to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741157/how-to-estimate-a-specific-infinite-sum a few days ago.

**Added examples**

If $k=1$ we know $S_{M,1} \approx (\sqrt{\pi} +2\sqrt{n}e^{-\pi^2})^n \approx 1.7726372048^n$.  I don't know a closed form approximation for any other value of $k$.

For $n=12$ and $k = 1, \dots, 12$ using computer code to approximate the sum we get $ 962.58329951, 267.409968069, 196.186732001, 171.404195004, 162.313077353, 158.96911585, 157.738949838, 157.286397212, 157.119912408, 157.058666071, 157.036134803, 157.027846013$.

In general it seems numerically that for every fixed $n$, $S_{M,k}$ converges fairly quickly to some value as $k$ increases towards $n$.

Comment: @AmirSagiv The sum is an instance of the Riemann Theta function which is why I added the theta-function tag. Specifically, it is $\theta(0|iM/\pi)$.

Comment: You might look at [multidimensional Theta functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/21) and references there.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you. I don't believe there exists a nice approximation for the Riemann Theta function in general but my problem has only two variables so I was hoping it might be much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $s = k-1$, and write $x^T M x = \|x\|^2 + s (e \cdot x)^2$ where $e = (1,\ldots,1)$.  Let $P_j = \{x \in \mathbb Z^n: e \cdot x = j\}$. Each $P_j$ is a translate of $P_0$, which is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z^n$.  Then

$$S_{M,k} = \sum_{j\in \mathbb Z} e^{-s j^2} \sum_{x \in P_j} e^{-\|x\|^2} = \sum_{j \in \mathbb Z} e^{-s j^2} T(j)$$

where $T(j) = \sum_{x \in P_j} e^{-\|x\|^2}$.
Now $P_{j+n} = e + P_j$, and if $x \in P_j$ we have $\|e + x\|^2 = n + 2 j + \|x\|^2$.  Thus
$$T(n+j) = e^{-n-2j} T(j)$$
so that $$T(mn + j) = e^{-m^2 n - 2 mj} T(j)$$
We just have to compute (or approximate) $T(0), \ldots, T(n-1)$, and 
then
$$\eqalign{S_{M,k} &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sum_{m \in \mathbb Z} e^{-s(j+mn)^2} e^{-m^2n-2mj} T(j)  = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e^{-sj^2} T(j) \sum_{m \in \mathbb Z}
e^{-(n^2s+n) m(m+2j/n)}\cr
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e^{-sj^2} T(j) \theta_3(i(ns+1)j, \exp(-n^2 s))}  $$ 
where $\theta_3$ is a Jacobi theta function.

Comment: If $k=n$, how quickly does this grow with $n$? Is it exponential for example?

Comment: Note that $x^T M x = \|x\|^2$ if $e \cdot x = 0$.  Let's say $n$ is even.  For any $y \in \mathbb Z^{n/2}$, the vector $x = (y_1,-y_1,y_2,-y_2,\ldots,y_{n/2},-y_{n/2})$ has $x^T M x = \|x\|^2 = 2 \|y\|^2$.  Thus
for any $k$, $$S_{M,k} \ge \sum_{y \in \mathbb Z^{n/2}} e^{-2 \|y\|^2} = \left(\sum_{y \in \mathbb Z} e^{-2 y^2}\right)^{n/2}$$
which does grow exponentially in $n$.

Answer (score 3):

This is an optimistic approach and since it is long, I write it as an answer. First we set $$H(M,x)=\Sigma_{x\in \mathbb{Z}^n}{e^{-x^TMx}},$$
Which is your introduced summation. Let $J$ be the all one matrix with size $n$ and $I$ be the identity matrix. Since we have:$$M=
kI+(k-1)(J-I),$$ we can see that the eigenvalues of the matrix $M$ are as follow:
$$\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_{n-1}=1,\lambda_n=(n+1)(k-1).$$ 
Let $D={\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n)$, which is a diagonal matrix of size $n$. Assume that $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n$ are the normalized eigenvectors of the later eigenvalues, respectively. Notice that you can find easily these eigenvectors in such a way that in the matrix $U=[u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n]$, each two columns are orthogonal. By spectral decomposition, we have:$$M=U^TDU.$$ Now, we define the below summation:
$$H(M,X)=\Sigma_{x_{ij}\in \mathbb{Z}}{e^{-X^TMX}},$$ where $X$ is an arbitrary integer matrix with size $n$. So, if we can estimate this summation, we can estimate an estimation for your summation. But, we have:
$$H(M,X)=\Sigma_{x_{ij}\in \mathbb{Z}}{e^{-(UX)^TMUX}}=(UX)^Te^{-D}UX=e^{-\lambda_1}p_1p_1^T+\cdots+e^{-\lambda_n}p_np_n^T=\frac{1}{e}({p_1p_1^T+p_2p_2^T+\cdots+p_{n-1}p_{n-1}^T})+\frac{1}{e^{(n+1)(k-1)}}p_np_n^T,$$where in the last summation, I supposed that $UX$ is invertible, since in almost all cases it is. Note that we have $p_i=y_i^Tu_i^T$, where $X=[y_1,\ldots,y_n]^T$. Now, since you know completely the eigenvectores of $M$, by some matrix inequality and some special values of the matrix $X$, you can find a good upper bound for this summation. I think it can be seen as integer linear optimization problem.

I think this approach can be optimized. Also, maybe there are some better way by using Fourier transformation.

Comment: could you define the values $p_n$?

Comment: @AmirSagiv: I added the definition of $p_n$.